# How do I split the responses from an SNMP array?

Tags: ruby, snmp

I've got the following sample response from a system when walking the tree:

```
[name=1.3.6.1.4.1.15248.2.5.1.3.1.1.8650, value=8650 (INTEGER)]
[name=1.3.6.1.4.1.15248.2.5.1.3.1.1.8651, value=8651 (INTEGER)]
[name=1.3.6.1.4.1.15248.2.5.1.3.1.2.8650, value=QNewsAK (OCTET STRING)]
[name=1.3.6.1.4.1.15248.2.5.1.3.1.2.8651, value=QSuite4AK (OCTET STRING)]
[name=1.3.6.1.4.1.15248.2.5.1.3.1.3.8650, value=46835255 (INTEGER)]
[name=1.3.6.1.4.1.15248.2.5.1.3.1.3.8651, value=11041721 (INTEGER)]
[name=1.3.6.1.4.1.15248.2.5.1.3.1.4.8650, value=8442357 (INTEGER)]
[name=1.3.6.1.4.1.15248.2.5.1.3.1.4.8651, value=5717570 (INTEGER)]
[name=1.3.6.1.4.1.15248.2.5.1.3.1.5.8650, value=0 (INTEGER)]
[name=1.3.6.1.4.1.15248.2.5.1.3.1.5.8651, value=0 (INTEGER)]
```

I've got two distinct sets of data here. I don't know how many rows I will eventually get, and as you can also see, the first pair of values are also part of the OID.

Printing them nicely obviously tidies it up, but if I want to use them once on each line, what's the best way to split it?

I might get up to eight distinct sets of values that I'll have to work with, so each line would be for example:

```
8650, QNewsAK, 46835255, 8442357, 0
```

Which are the "ID", "Name", "Size", "Free", and "Status", where status is ordinarily non-zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a starting point using [`group_by`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) to do the heavy-lifting:

```
SNMP_RESPONSE = [
  '[name=1.3.6.1.4.1.15248.2.5.1.3.1.1.8650, value=8650 (INTEGER)]',
  '[name=1.3.6.1.4.1.15248.2.5.1.3.1.1.8651, value=8651 (INTEGER)]',
  '[name=1.3.6.1.4.1.15248.2.5.1.3.1.2.8650, value=QNewsAK (OCTET STRING)]',
  '[name=1.3.6.1.4.1.15248.2.5.1.3.1.2.8651, value=QSuite4AK (OCTET STRING)]',
  '[name=1.3.6.1.4.1.15248.2.5.1.3.1.3.8650, value=46835255 (INTEGER)]',
  '[name=1.3.6.1.4.1.15248.2.5.1.3.1.3.8651, value=11041721 (INTEGER)]',
  '[name=1.3.6.1.4.1.15248.2.5.1.3.1.4.8650, value=8442357 (INTEGER)]',
  '[name=1.3.6.1.4.1.15248.2.5.1.3.1.4.8651, value=5717570 (INTEGER)]',
  '[name=1.3.6.1.4.1.15248.2.5.1.3.1.5.8650, value=0 (INTEGER)]',
  '[name=1.3.6.1.4.1.15248.2.5.1.3.1.5.8651, value=0 (INTEGER)]',
]

SNMP_RESPONSE.group_by{ |s| s.split(',').first[/\d+$/] }
```

Which returns:

```
{
    "8650" => [
        [0] "[name=1.3.6.1.4.1.15248.2.5.1.3.1.1.8650, value=8650 (INTEGER)]",
        [1] "[name=1.3.6.1.4.1.15248.2.5.1.3.1.2.8650, value=QNewsAK (OCTET STRING)]",
        [2] "[name=1.3.6.1.4.1.15248.2.5.1.3.1.3.8650, value=46835255 (INTEGER)]",
        [3] "[name=1.3.6.1.4.1.15248.2.5.1.3.1.4.8650, value=8442357 (INTEGER)]",
        [4] "[name=1.3.6.1.4.1.15248.2.5.1.3.1.5.8650, value=0 (INTEGER)]"
    ],
    "8651" => [
        [0] "[name=1.3.6.1.4.1.15248.2.5.1.3.1.1.8651, value=8651 (INTEGER)]",
        [1] "[name=1.3.6.1.4.1.15248.2.5.1.3.1.2.8651, value=QSuite4AK (OCTET STRING)]",
        [2] "[name=1.3.6.1.4.1.15248.2.5.1.3.1.3.8651, value=11041721 (INTEGER)]",
        [3] "[name=1.3.6.1.4.1.15248.2.5.1.3.1.4.8651, value=5717570 (INTEGER)]",
        [4] "[name=1.3.6.1.4.1.15248.2.5.1.3.1.5.8651, value=0 (INTEGER)]"
    ]
}
```

The hash can be manipulated further:

```
groups = SNMP_RESPONSE.group_by{ |s| s.split(',').first[/\d+$/] }
values = groups.map{ |key, ary| ary.map{ |s| s[/value=(\S+)/, 1] } }
```

`values` looks like:

```
[
    [0] [
        [0] "8650",
        [1] "QNewsAK",
        [2] "46835255",
        [3] "8442357",
        [4] "0"
    ],
    [1] [
        [0] "8651",
        [1] "QSuite4AK",
        [2] "11041721",
        [3] "5717570",
        [4] "0"
    ]
]
```

A bit more massaging gives:

```
puts values.map{ |a| a.join(', ') }
```

Which outputs:

```
8650, QNewsAK, 46835255, 8442357, 0
8651, QSuite4AK, 11041721, 5717570, 0
```